# Que tipo de dato se puede ingresar numeros con coma?

Tags: java, netbeans

He intentado con double, float y ninguno de esos me sale cual codigo se utiliza para eso??

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado escueta. ¿La coma la quieres introducir dentro del código fuente? ¿La introduce el usuario? ¿Es el separador decimal?

Answer (score 3):

No puedes usar "números con coma", en java se utiliza punto. Recibe el "número" como string y conviértelo a numérico usando *java.text.DecimalFormat*.

```
    String s = "1,23";
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    Number n;
    try {
        n = formatter.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo con NumberFormat y Locale que es mas estándar para lo que necesitas, recuerda que a la hora de imprimir un valor en consola java siempre tomara el punto como el separador decimal a menos que apliquemos un NumberFormat para generar el valor de salida:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ConvertNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String x = "1,234";

        Number number = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(x);
        System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
        // Respuesta 1.234

        number = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).parse(x);
        System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
        // Respuesta 1234.0

        Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
        number = NumberFormat.getInstance(spanish).parse(x);
        System.out.println(number.doubleValue());
        // Respuesta 1.234

        // y para imprimir con formato en consola
        Locale spanish2 = new Locale("es", "ES");
        Double value = 12.234;
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(spanish2).format(value));
        // Respuesta 12,234
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta colocando punto y no coma. Por ejemplo:

```
float num = 1.5
```

Comment: Pero el problema es que me pide que ingrese coma.